# Compound Index for MongoDB with Sorting and Range

Tags: mongodb

I have such kind of query:

```js
db.contacts.find({createdAt: {$gte: 1458585000000, $lte: 1461349799000},
                  asset_type: "personal", 
                  createdBy: "pxedNoPZzGAdx2fnK", 
                  status: "done"})
           .sort({createdAt: -1})
```

Is it possible to write a compound index for such kind of query that includes both range and sort?

I have created a compound index such:

```
contacts._ensureIndex({createdAt: 1, asset_type: 1, createdBy: 1, status: 1});
```

Will this compound index work?

Comment: That index should work, but use [`explain`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) to confirm.

Comment: BTW: Not sure if your statement is correct, I don't understand why you use the underscore before `ensureIndex` ... Shouldn't be: `db.contacts.ensureIndex({createdAt: 1, asset_type: 1, createdBy: 1, status: 1})` instead?

Answer (score 0):

as @JohnnyHK is suggesting, this index may work, but that doesn't necessary mean you're going to gain in efficiency if you use the query you posted. The commands like `$gte` and `$lte` can use the indexes but they can be inefficient. Take a look to this video from the official YouTube channel of MongoDB: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1sADN-NKwhY

In addition, when you use a compound index, you need to care about the order you put the fields in your query, which is correct in your case.